# Why this program gives address in output?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>  
  
int add(int, int); // function prototype  
  
int main()  
{  
    int a, b;  
  
    // printf("Enter 2 integer numbers\n");  
    // scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);  
  
    //function call add(a, b);  
    printf(" %d + %d = %d \n", a, b, add(2, 7));
```

**Please focus on this line why it gives address + 0 = 9//**

```
    return 0;  
}  
  
//function definition  
int add(int x, int y)  
{  
    return x+y;  
}
```

// produces outPut :  199164000 + 0 = 9

Comment: `a` and `b` are uninitialized, and it's not addresses, but a garbage values.

Comment: What output did _you_ expect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior)

Comment: It makes a lot more sense to put `int a = 2, b = 7;` and then `printf(" %d + %d = %d \n", a, b, add(a, b));`

Answer (score 0):

You commented the scanf function and also didn't given values for the a and b. So it printed garbage values. You also need to pass a and b into the add(a,b) function.

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int add(int, int); // function prototype  

int main()  
{  
    int a, b;  

    // printf("Enter 2 integer numbers\n");  
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);  

    //function call add(a, b);  
    printf(" %d + %d = %d \n", a, b, add(a, b)); 

    return 0;  
}  

//function definition  
int add(int x, int y)  
{  
    return x+y;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not printing any address. It is printing garbage values. You have not given any values to the variable a and b. So it will print garbage values. Why you commented scanf statement. Just stop commenting it and it will work.